# Is saying "I mistaken her for you" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage

Is saying "I mistaken her for you" grammatically correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No. "Mistaken" is an adjective, but the sentence calls for a verb. You should say, "I mistook her for you" -- "mistook" is a verb. Or, "She was mistaken for you" if you want to use the adjective, but then you lose that it was the speaker who made the mistake.

Comment: Or, of course, "I have mistaken her for you." @foreverlearner4, the simple answer to your simple question is "no, it's not correct." To suggest a correction we'd need to know what meaning is intended.

Comment: If I want to tell my friend that I mistook her sister for her, what should I say?